# How to change default message from user relationships module?

Tags: users

I am using [User Relationships](https://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) module. Its working fine. But I want to change a default message which get displayed on user site after getting request.

The message is like

> "John has requested to be your Friend. View your pending relationship requests to approve or decline."

I want same message to be displayed as

> "John has requested to be your Friend. View your pending friend requests to approve or decline."

Just want to replace the word relationship with friend. How can I do that?

Comment: try disable messages module to disable the message and rules to add a message on an event that you specify in the ui.

Answer (score 0):

`User Relationship` module allows you to set your own message, you can override the default message by settting a variable using `variable_set("user_relationships_msg_{$key}", "Custom Message")`, check the functions `user_relationships_get_message()` and `_user_relationships_default_messages()`.

Comment: I have tried this. But it is replacing all the site wide words. For an instance Relationship word in view's edit page. Since the above message is  having link in it, we cant change the whole sentence using String overrides module.

Comment: @D-pak Updated the answer

Comment: Ok wolverine I will do that, but what if my module gets updated. Will the changes remain same? or will all changed get back to the default again?

Comment: Implement `hook_enable()` in your module install file and set the variables, similarly in `hook_disable()` delete the variables. In that way the changes will be there as long as your module is enabled.